# Objects in Java Map not accessing properties

Tags: java, maps

I made some objects and I put them into a Map<Integer, Object> pairs.
When I iterate through the map, I can't access any of the properties of the objects, they show up as null but the object is present and can be confirmed through

```
inventory2.containsValue(objName);
```

---

```
public class Obj {

    public String name;
    public int quantity;

    public Obj(String name, int quantity) {
        name = this.name;
        quantity = this.quantity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "obj [name=" + name + ", quantity="
                + quantity + "]";
    }
```

```
public static void mapReview() {

    Map<Integer, Obj> inventory2 = new HashMap<>();
    Obj greenHerb = new Obj("Green Herb",2);
    Obj redHerb = new Obj("Red Herb", 4);

    for(int k = 0; k < inventory2.size(); k++) {
        System.out.println("Key is: " + k + " and name is: " + inventory2.get(k).getName() + " and quantity is: " + inventory2.get(k).getQuantity());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor assignments are wrong, they should be the other way around.

Instead of:

```
name = this.name;
quantity = this.quantity;
```

It should be:

```
this.name = name;
this.quantity = quantity;
```

Comment: Jeez, I tried iterating through it so many other ways but the problem was in the constructor. Thanks.

Comment: @DazedandConfucius https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger